# Is it possible to change JavaScript array data with onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Google chart which gets some data from a PHP script when loading the site.

Its very simple in fact, when the site gets loaded a PHP script does import some data from a textfile, if I could change the textfile name with a onclick event then I would have already what I need, but I don't know how or if any way it is possible.

Please take a look at my current code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>Crypto Curreny Trader</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          
    function drawChart() 
    {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 

<?php
 $filename="Charts/Chart_".$_GET['chartname']."_.txt";
 if(file_exists($filename))
    {
    $page = file_get_contents($bitcoinkurse);
    $page = json_decode($page,true);
    $a=0;
    for($i=0; $i<count($page["Chart"]); $i++)
    {
      if($a>0)echo ',';
      echo "['".$i."', ".str_replace(",","",$page["Chart"][$i]["high"]).", ".str_replace(",","",$page["Chart"][$i]["open"]).", ".str_replace(",","",$page["Chart"][$i]["close"]).", ".str_replace(",","",$page["Chart"][$i]["low"])."]
       ";
      $a++;
    }
    }
?>

            ], true);

    var options = { 
      legend: 'none'

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The result from that code above, after the PHP have insert the data looks like following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Crypto Curreny Trader</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      
function drawChart() 
{
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([ 
        ['0', 9.238, 1.776624, 4.28371496, 3.281148]
       ,['1', 4.457042626, 4.267909653, 3.314327907, 2.652562]
       ,['2', 4.70925, 3.314327907, 3.7506, 3.1796541]
       ,['3', 4.2841969, 3.78917, 3.69225, 3.1719]
       ,['4', 6.435, 3.75165, 5.631798674, 3.177]
       ,['5', 7.522635, 5.6167294, 5.50684251, 4.1059122]
       ,['6', 6.7642005, 5.51420298, 5.45737647, 4.306905495]
       ,['7', 5.732702311, 5.387799545, 4.806317079, 3.82402]
       ,['8', 5.4066429, 4.812088546, 4.68895929, 4.22425]
       ,['9', 6.604752495, 4.688988639, 4.953611982, 3.7459]
       ,['10', 5.731039869, 4.98248236, 5.08876956, 4.375207798]
       ,['11', 5.691860745, 5.161199095, 5.37876, 4.59]
       ,['12', 11.106871122, 5.37962832, 8.568796729, 5.0271078]
       ,['13', 10.69998444, 8.577491, 8.07145491, 7.49101]
       ,['14', 10.314, 8.046091743, 8.38063401, 7.134387304]
       ,['15', 10.195816064, 8.29028778, 7.59825472, 6.05024]
       ,['16', 9.7715841, 7.59825472, 8.650969572, 6.80476425]
       ,['17', 12.364981076, 8.835323304, 10.02916863, 7.575533]
       ,['18', 11.12854414, 9.91944866, 8.8670113, 7.2400612]
       ,['19', 12.2264, 8.931092222, 10.404, 8.136216735]
       ,['20', 11.031294816, 10.4004022, 9.211090911, 7.878786]
       ,['21', 9.925731708, 9.231426, 7.845301028, 5.98728]
       ,['22', 8.711378172, 7.89030096, 7.91424576, 6.35]
       ,['23', 8.4564, 7.921346195, 7.994833212, 7.2642595]
        ], true);

var options = { 
  legend: 'none'

};

var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

So everything is working fine, but I want to change the textfile from which the data is load with a JavaScript onclick event, is that possible?

I know I can use a HTML a Tag and let the site be load new to give the PHP the instruction to load data from a new file, but I want to know if I can do this without loading the site new, just with using a JavaScript onclick event.

Comment: What do you mean by *"i want to change the text file from which the data is load with a javascript onclick "*? Do you mean you only want to load the textfile data when a `onclick` event takes place? If so then you can use ajax to query/call a `php` file and have that return the text file data. For more information about using `AJAX` please read [**MDN Web Docs AJAX**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: FYI: Using `json_encode` on a complete data object to get code that you can be used as javascript, is a lot easier than trying to build it through string manipulation

Comment: "*Is it possible to change Javascript array data with onclick event?*" ... Yes. If you want to change the file with onclick, fire off an ajax call to a php script which then the php script will change the file (and can even return the new data as a response).

Comment: Also for renaming a file via `php` you can use **rename()** or more information about the rename()
 function you can read more [**rename function documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: in the textfile i have store the chart data and i want to be able to change the chart data with giving a new textfile name from which everythink should be load.

Comment: at moment everythink is static because when the site gets load then all data is importet from aa textfile which is given before, but i can not change the textfile at moment without loading the complete site new. and thats why i was thinking if maybe with javascript i could do that.

Comment: You can use `php` to open/read/edit text files. I would recommend you research some `php` tutorials for opening/reading/editing/creating files but if you are going to use `php` to create new files be sure this cannot be access by visitors. If you do then I would highly recommend you filter/validate the content before saving the data on your server/hosting.

Comment: Is it not possible to change the Javascript Data Array with some new data and letting the chart be draw with the new data?

Comment: Yes it is possible. But how do you want to do it? You keep bouncing between two completely different issues here. Focus your question, ask ONE question, and stick with it.

Comment: I think a solution where you change the Javescript Array Data with new Data from another textfile is easyer then changing the textfile data with php or?

Comment: @MaikSilber I think I have confused your intentions of changing the data. you can change the javascript array but those changes will not be saved or update the textfile. Can you explain what is currently happening and what you wish to do "the changes" please? I'm assuming you have an array from a textfile but with what content and where is the content coming from that you want to change the array with and are you expecting those changes to be saved in the text file?

Comment: i have many different textfiles and in every textfile there is data for a chart and i want to be able to tell the chart load new data from textfile x. at moment the data is always load from same textfile i want to create some buttons in my site with which the chart should be change, without loading the complete site from new, because that i know is possible to do with PHP but i want to give the chart new data from new textfile with a javascript onclick event

Comment: I understand what you want now. I would recommend you use `ajax` to query a `php` file with the file name so that the `php` can get the contents of that file, return them in the ajax response which will then enable you to apply them to the chart. If you place the text files in a directory you could use `php` to read the directory to return all the file names and you could have a droplist with a change event to execute the `ajax`. This way you can upload new text files and the list/options to choose from will automatically be added.